# nginx proxy_pass from a specific path to another specific path throws an error

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I read and reread the [nginx proxy_pass docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass). I thought I understood it until I spent the last hour getting a nondescript error that doesn't make sense. Other people with the same problem don't seem related to this. Yesterday was my first day with nginx. I'm running nginx v1.12.2.

When someone requests `https://example1.com/just-right/search` I want to proxy that request to `https://example2.com/abc.php`

```
location ~ /just-right/search {
    proxy_pass   https://example2.com/abc.php;
}
```

Instead of proxying the path defined in proxy_pass I get the error:

```
"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in line .......
```

I'm not using a regular expression. What does 'named location' mean? It's not inside of an if statement or "limit_except" block, so what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use tilde (~) in your location block, location is interpreted as a regular expression match.  Remove that and it should process without error.

See documentation here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: Thanks. The location line was 30 and the error pointed at line 31, so I was only looking at the proxy_pass line.